# adding mimetypes in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mime-type

Ok, so here's what I want to do:

I have a file with a specific extension (*.ipynb) that I want to connect with a specific program. Ubuntu however thinks it is a `text/plain` file.

There are a lot of questions about this topic here on AskUbuntu, but non of them worked. I also tried to follow the instructions that are given here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingMimeTypes
- did not work.

Since this is definitely a problem a lot of users experience, can anyone post an answer that explains how to do this?

Comment: This works for me https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_Applications#Custom_file_associations

Comment: Yeah that works!!! Thanks! If you want to put that together in an answer I'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This worked for me as well!  Figured I might as well post it as an answer -
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_Applications#Custom_file_associations :

> ### Custom file associations
>
> The following method creates a custom mime type and file association
>   manually. This is useful if your desktop does not have a mime
>   type/file association editor installed. In this example, a fictional
>   multimedia application 'foobar' will be associated with all *.foo
>   files. This will only affect the current user.
>
> First, create the file
>   `~/.local/share/mime/packages/application-x-foobar.xml`:
>
> ```
> mkdir -p ~/.local/share/mime/packages
> cd ~/.local/share/mime/packages
> touch application-x-foobar.xml
> ```
>
> Then edit `~/.local/share/mime/packages/application-x-foobar.xml` and
>   add this text:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
>     <mime-type type="application/x-foobar">
>         <comment>foo file</comment>
>         <icon name="application-x-foobar"/>
>         <glob-deleteall/>
>         <glob pattern="*.foo"/>
>     </mime-type>
> </mime-info>
> ```
>
> Note that you can use any icon, including one for another application.
>
> Next, edit or create the file
>   `~/.local/share/applications/foobar.desktop` to contain something
>   like:
>
> ```
> [Desktop Entry]
> Name=Foobar
> Exec=/usr/bin/foobar
> MimeType=application/x-foobar
> Icon=foobar
> Terminal=false
> Type=Application
> Categories=AudioVideo;Player;Video;
> Comment=
> ```
>
> Note that Categories should be set appropriately for the application
>   type (in this example, a multimedia app).
>
> Now update the applications and mime database with:
>
> ```
> update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications
> update-mime-database    ~/.local/share/mime
> ```
>
> Programs that use mime types, such as file managers, should now open
>   *.foo files with foobar. (You may need to restart your file manager to see the change.)