# How to set default application for a specific file extension

Tags: files, default, default-programs

I am trying to set meshlab as the default application to open .obj files.

I attempted (as mentioned in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606858/how-to-set-default-program-to-open-specific-file-type)) right click a random obj file -> properties -> Open With -> there is no meshlab to choose from and there is no way I can add meshlab into it.

The weird thing is when I do the same step for .ply file, there actually is an option to choose meshlab to set as the default application.

Now I need to open meshlab first, and drag the obj file in it, which is a lot more hassle than just double clicking the obj file to open it.

What should I do so I can open .obj files with meshlab by default?

Comment: I think that question you linked has the solution: Install Ubuntu-Tweak, go to Admins, click on File Type Manager, change the default application for .obj files.

Comment: @wjandrea I tried, but there is no file type called OBJ that I can change.

Comment: I think you'll need to create a MIME type, then set the file association. From a quick Google, here's [method 1](http://askubuntu.com/a/555936), and method 2 [part 1](http://askubuntu.com/a/179874) and [part 2](http://askubuntu.com/a/289339).

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks the third link solves it for me. If you write up an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, run `mimetype` on your file to get the mimetype as follows:

```
$ mimetype bunny.obj 
bunny.obj: application/x-tgif
```

Once you've determined the corresponding mimetype, add your application as the default in `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`:

```
$ sudo su
$ echo "application/x-tgif=meshlab.desktop" >> /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

It's important to use **two** > symbols in the command above, not one. Consider making a backup of /usr/share/applications/defaults.list beforehand as well.

Comment: Better to do this as user config in `~/.config/mimeapps.list`